# Ruby, class and inheritance

Tags: ruby, inheritance

I need help understanding inheritance.

```
class MyArray < Array
end

a = MyArray[1, 2, 3] #=> [1, 2, 3]
b = MyArray[4, 5]    #=> [4, 5]
c = a + b            #=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

a.class #=> MyArray
b.class #=> MyArray
c.class #=> Array
```

I don't understand why the result of the addition is not an instance of `MyArray` class.

Comment: Worth reading: [Beware subclassing Ruby core classes](https://words.steveklabnik.com/beware-subclassing-ruby-core-classes)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I don't understand why my array "a" is not "MyArray" class after add.

Why should it (be a `MyArray`)? Concatenation operation on arrays is defined to return a new `Array`, so that's what happens here. https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.3/Array.html#method-i-2B

If you want, you can override that operation in your class to return an instance of MyArray. Don't forget about all other similar methods.

This is also why it's a bad idea to subclass standard collections. Better to use composition over inheritance here.

Comment: Ok, I understand. But I want to define other methods on my objects MyArray. How i can do that ?

Comment: @µgeek:what do you mean? Just like you define any other method.

Comment: Yes i want to define method, for exemple to compare 2 array, or cut array to two other array...

Comment: But I also want to be able to use the methods of arrays

Comment: Do I only have to insert methods in Array class ?

Comment: @µgeek Not sure what you meant by this, but looks like you'll benefit from proceeding with the  ruby tutorial/book/whatever you're using, and trying simpler exercises for now (ones not involving subclassing standard classes). If my memory serves, the pickaxe book used an excellent song library app as examples.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I'll try simpler exercises... Is it really a bad way to add methods to a standard class?

Comment: @µgeek: yes, you should refrain from doing that, until you can explain _why_ you need that and why other approaches are not good enough.

Comment: _"Concatenation operation is defined to return a new Array"_ – the documentation just says "array" (lowercase), the class isn't specified. And other methods like `a[1..2]` or `a * 2` which also return a "new array" actually retain the receiver's class, i.e. they do return `MyArray` instances.  _"Why should it be a MyArray?"_ – because it would be less surprising. I think the conversion back to `Array` is due to optimization rather than OOP consideration.

Comment: "a[1..2] or a * 2 ... return MyArray instances" - oh wow, totally did not expect this.

Answer (score 3):

Just to add a bit to Sergio's answer in terms of his comment on using composition over inheritance and the exchange in the comments.

Instead of saying MyArray *is* an array you can say MyArrayLike *has* and array.
Then you can "forward" methods that make sense to the underlying array but still add your own functionality that makes sense for your class **without** sub-classing array.

Ruby even has several ways to make this very easy including the [Forwardable](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/forwardable/rdoc/Forwardable.html) module.

```
class MyArrayLike 
   attr_reader :arr 
   def initialize( initial_arr )
      @arr = initial_arr 
   end

   def +(other)
     result = self.class.new(arr + other.arr)
     # maybe you want to do more than just concat the underlying array, if so you can do it here
     result
   end

   def first
      # for example maybe you want first to just return the first item in the underlying array.
      arr.first 
   end    
end


a = MyArrayLike.new([1,2,3])
b = MyArrayLike.new([4,5])

puts "a.class = #{a.class}"
# => a.class = MyArrayLike
puts a
# => #<MyArrayLike:0x00000000dc4b00>
a += b
puts "a.class = #{a.class}"
# => a.class = MyArrayLike
puts a 
# => #<MyArrayLike:0x00000000dc4470>

puts a.first 
# => 1
puts a.arr 
# => 1
#    2
#    3
#    4
#    5
```

Answer (score 3):

Adding `MyArray` to `MyArray` to get `Array` may be counterintuitive, but a method can be defined to return any class. And in the case of `Array#+`, which you are calling, it just happens to be defined to return an `Array`. That's it.

If you want it to return a `MyArray`, one way to do it is to define `MyArray#+` as follows:

```
class MyArray < Array
  def +other
    MyArray.new(super)
  end
end

(MyArray.new([1, 2, 3]) + MyArray.new([4, 5])).class # => MyArray
```

By the way, notice that your `MyArray#initialize` definition is meaningless, and hence redundant.

Comment: Alternative implementation: `dup.concat(other)`